# class as argument, scala.

Tags: scala, metaprogramming

as a simplified version of my code:

```
abstract class GenX
case class X1 extends GenX
case class X2 extends GenX
...

class A {
 val ab : LinkedList[X1] = LinkedList()
 val ac : LinkedList[X2] = LinkedList()
 ...
 def addX[T <: GenX]( x : GenX, clazz : T) =
   getList(clazz) append LinkedList(x) // HERE complains

 def getList(T <: GenX) (clazz : T) : LinkedList[_<: GenX] = clazz match {
  case X1 => ab
  case X2 => ac
  ...
  }
}
```

my intention is that when a GenX needs to be added to A, it can pass its class as argument for a generic addition like

```
case class X1 extends GenX{
 def addToA(a : A) = a.addX(this, this getClass)
}
```

the problem now is that compiler complains bout x being of GenX type and not _$1 <: GenX type

I dont get it.

Comment: a personal note, i dont think that `def addToA(a : A) = a.ab append LinkedList(this)` is a good solution, for encapsulation issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, with regard to appending, I would suggest using something like a `ListBuffer` rather than a `LinkedList`, it has a much friendlier API for appending.

Next, your declaration of the `clazz` argument declares it to be of type `T` (subtype of `GenX`), not `Class[T]`. You are better off just matching on `x`, anyway.

Finally, `x` is declared as of type `GenX`, and for all the compiler can tell is potentially a different subclass of `GenX` from `clazz` or the subclass type of the selected list, hence the actual compilation error you would have received.

Here is a version of A that should achieve what you are trying for:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

class A {
  val ab : ListBuffer[X1] = ListBuffer()
  val ac : ListBuffer[X2] = ListBuffer()
  // ...

  def addX(x: GenX) = x match {
    case x1: X1 => ab += x1
    case x2: X2 => ac += x2
    // ...
  }         
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that solved my problem. I was so concentrated on the problem, i didnt realize i could mix addX and getList.
Just to know, what would have been the returning type of getList with your version because `: ListBuffer[GenX]` is a compiling error, but i think it actually is a ListBuffer[GenX].

Comment: Something that looks pretty weird at first glance, I think. When I tried the above in the REPL, `a.addX(x)` gave back a result of (approx) `ListBuffer[_ >: X1 with X2 <: GenX]`. I think this should be interpreted as though there are brackets around the `X1 with X2` part (and this would extend out to `... with X3 with ...` for more subtypes of GenX involved).

Comment: oh, pretty nasty stuff it is then. I wanted to know the returning type because now i need a `removeX(x : GenX)` and it is basically the same code except from `+= xn`. but if it is that wired, i'll just go with a copy&paste changing the end of each case.
Thanks again